# Why do bonds interact with other bonds and exhibit overlapping effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, hyperconjugation

In carbocations, alkenes and carbon free radicals during hyperconjugation, overlapping of molecular orbitals take place. So how and why does this happen?